# Ubuntu 18.04 Application menu not showing after clicking

Tags: 18.04, appmenu

I Updated my Ubuntu from 17.10 to 18.04 now the Application menu on top is not showing the drop down when clicked on it.

The Places Menu is Working but the left Applications Drop down is not working:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9immy.png]

Found a related [post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2382538&page=1) but no solution

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt install gnome-menus`?

Comment: Output: `gnome-menus is already the newest version (3.13.3-11ubuntu1).`

Answer (score 6):

You have to activate "hot corners" with gnome-tweak-tools.

It worked for me.

I found this solution here : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/

Comment: a. what's gnome-tweak-tools - are you referring to Gnome Tweak Tool? b. what's that link got to do with gnome-tweak-tools?

Answer (score 3):

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Then edit `metadata.json`

```
sudo nano metadata.json
```

Edit the Shell Version

```
{
"extension-id": "apps-menu",
"uuid": "apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com",
"gettext-domain": "gnome-shell-extensions",
"name": "Applications Menu",
"description": "Add a category-based menu for applications.\nThis extension is part of Classic Mode and is officially supported by GNOME. Please do not report bugs using the form below, use GNOME's GitLab instance instead.",
"original-authors": [ "e2002@bk.ru", "debarshir@gnome.org" ],
"shell-version": [ "3.28.1" ], // add your shell version
"url": "https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions"
}
```

Press `ctrl+o` to save the file and `ctrl+x` to exit

Get Shell Version by typing : `gnome-shell --version`

Then Logout and Login again, This fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks, same problem here, extension has 3.28 version. I changed to 3.28.1 and this worked perfectly!

Comment: I changed it from 3.28 to 3.28.1. Did not work for me. Still broken. Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Go to Tweaks,then Top Bar, and "turn on" the Activities Overview Hot Corner. Applications menu will appear.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of the the two answers by Rakesh Roy and PhJ worked for me. You have to both activate the hot corners and also change shell version to 3.28.1.