# application menu and places menu are not showing in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, appmenu, places, gnome-tweaks

I have recently dual booted Ubuntu. Realized sometime ago that there should be an application menu and places menu. I did all I could to solve the problem using gnome-tweaks. I also referred to this [Ubuntu 18.04 Application menu not showing after clicking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032999/ubuntu-18-04-application-menu-not-showing-after-clicking) but could not solve the problem.

Here is a pic of my settings:

[image: pc settings]

This is my desktop pic:

[image: desktop screenshot]

One more thing the 'metadat.json' file in my case was not stored at 'apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com' but at 'ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com'.

I want the app menu and places menu as shown below:

[image: app and places menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu by default does not have an "Application" menu and a "Places" menu, so it is very normal you do not see it. You can, however, use officially supported Gnome Shell extensions to add an "Application" and "Places" menu in the top bar.

To achieve that:

1. Install official gnome shell extensions and, if you do not yet have it, gnome-tweaks with the terminal command:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweaks
   ```
2. Open gnome-tweaks, and on the "Extensions" tab, enable the extensions "Applications menu", and "Places status indicator".

You may also hide the Ubuntu Dock and activate the "Window list" to have a more classical experience with buttons at the bottom of the screen for switching between windows.

Comment: Thank you very much. The command added the extensions. I could not find the cog icon on the login screen. Instead, I used the gnome-tweaks to enable the extensions for places and application menu.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I noticed that one needs to install "gnome-session-flashback" for the session to become available in the cog menu. I will update my answer, despite the fact that you already found a creative solution.

Comment: Nope, I am wrong. That session-flashback does not use Gnome Shell, but uses the classical metacity window manager with gnome-panel.